# Hide action bar in Android API Level 16(v4.1) or Higher

Tags: android

I am using this code from google to hide action bar but when I run, my application stop and throw error

> Unfortunately, Your App has stopped.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error trace.

Comment: replace getActionBar();to getSupportActionBar();

Comment: will you please put logcat output about error

Comment: My problem has solved by replacing getActionBar(); to getSupportActionBar(); Thanks :) @vishal-patoliya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:replace**

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

to

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: I have another issue when i check internet is connected or not my application stopped and show alert "Unfortunately, Your App has stopped."
My Code
boolean isConnect = false;
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (cm != null) {
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (activeNetwork != null) {
                    isConnect = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
                    return isConnect;
                }
            }
            return false;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using theme with "NoActionBar" then getActionBar() will return null.
Please post logcat messages for more details